# How to get similarties and differences between two images using Opencv

Tags: opencv

I want to compare two images and find same and different parts of images. I tired **"cv::compare  and cv::absdiff"** methods but confused which one can good for my case. Both show me different results. So how i can achieve my desired task ?

Comment: depends on what you are interested in. But `cv::absdiff` should more often be suitable because it tells you how much each pixel differs from the one in the other image. But keep in mind that both methods are only meaningful if both images are perfectly aligned. For example it might be ok to use `cv::absdiff` to compare a lossy compressed and a non-compressed image but it might not be suitable to compare two images of the same scene with slightly different camera position and/or different illumination.

Comment: @Micka Images are already align. Now i want to find construct a new image which contain similar area between both images how i can do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example how you can use `cv::absdiff` to find image similarities:

```
int main()
{
    cv::Mat input1 = cv::imread("../inputData/Similar1.png");
    cv::Mat input2 = cv::imread("../inputData/Similar2.png");

    cv::Mat diff;
    cv::absdiff(input1, input2, diff);

    cv::Mat diff1Channel;
    // WARNING: this will weight channels differently! - instead you might want some different metric here. e.g. (R+B+G)/3 or MAX(R,G,B)
    cv::cvtColor(diff, diff1Channel, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    float threshold = 30; // pixel may differ only up to "threshold" to count as being "similar"

    cv::Mat mask = diff1Channel < threshold;

    cv::imshow("similar in both images" , mask);

    // use similar regions in new image: Use black as background
    cv::Mat similarRegions(input1.size(), input1.type(), cv::Scalar::all(0));

    // copy masked area
    input1.copyTo(similarRegions, mask);


    cv::imshow("input1", input1);
    cv::imshow("input2", input2);
    cv::imshow("similar regions", similarRegions);
    cv::imwrite("../outputData/Similar_result.png", similarRegions);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Using those 2 inputs:

[image]

[image]

You'll observe that output (black background):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the great example :).

Comment: I implemented your code, but result was not 100 percent accurate as you got in your example. I do not know how to post images in comment here to show you.

Comment: probably because of noise between the images. using absdiff for similarity is a very simple approach! you can upload images on image hosting websites and copy link to comment

Comment: Here are the images   http://i.stack.imgur.com/huaya.jpg
   http://i.stack.imgur.com/7BsA5.jpg
   http://i.stack.imgur.com/0yH7C.jpg

Comment: you can vary "threshold" to adjust the result but it wont help in all cases, since "per-pixel" similarity might not be the perfect solution at all.

Comment: Is there any other suggested solution for this task ?

Comment: for general purpose and real world conditions not in controllable environment it is still a research topic. btw, whats so bad about the result image youve posted? what kind of a result did you expect?

Comment: I also want that black car out out of the result. :)

Comment: but the black colored car has nearly the same color as the shadow of the tree ;) and the front of the black car is "detected" correctly. To improve that you'll probably have to go very deep into computer vision, read some books and test many implementations. If you want to try another simple method, try "edge detection" ... for example dont compute absdiff of pixel colors but absdiff of image gradient. If you want to stay at that color thing, maybe try to convert the images to HSV format and differ between changes in color information and changes in brightness. and many more ways you can try

Comment: btw, at the moment that code doesnt handle color at all!

Comment: Ok i will try these approaches. Thanks.

Comment: Yes the problem is black shadow and car color i want to manage that some how.

Comment: simple: instead of `cv::cvtColor(diff, diff1Channel, CV_BGR2GRAY);` use cv::split and perform the same operations for each channel. Maybe better: convert to HSV and perform the operations on hue channel but ignore regions where saturation isn't appropriate.

Comment: Alright. Look bit complex will try to implement it :)

Comment: So how i can check those areas who have not appropriate saturation ?

Comment: for example if saturation < some threshold, the hue value isnt meaningful. unfortunately I'm no expert in color spaces...