# How to get position that defference between two images using opencv in android

Tags: android, opencv3.1

I'm from Russia. I'm learning Android. I'd like to compare two images using OpenCV. I would like to get position that difference between two images. What functions should I use? thanks

Comment: Try here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32583873/how-to-get-similarties-and-differences-between-two-images-using-opencv

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CV - Extract differences between two images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035672/cv-extract-differences-between-two-images)

Comment: @Blackcoat77 hello,thanks for your reply .i'd like get the square to show difference. how to get small  square?

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla hello i wanna get small square of difference between two images

Comment: @Pyotr... have you solved your problem..? If so then post your solution as a new answer to complete your question entry. Thanks.